# HttpURLConnection mobile network

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, 3g

I'm having trouble to connect to a webservice through HttpURLConnection when using 3g (any mobile network). I don't know exactly the problem because when it's on the wifi, it works perfectly. When I check for the errorStream, it says that the buffer length is unknown. Why does it happen only through 3g?

My code is:

```
        if (method_type == 0) {
            param = url[0].concat("?identificacao=" + postDataParam.get("identificacao") + "&senha=" + postDataParam.get("senha"));
            System.out.println(param);
            try{
                URL link = new URL(param);
                HttpURLConnection e = (HttpURLConnection)link.openConnection();
                e.setReadTimeout(15000);
                e.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                e.setRequestMethod("GET");
                e.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
                e.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64CredenciaisCodificadas);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(e.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();

                resposta = response.toString();

                globalResposta = resposta;

                senhaCorreta = Boolean.parseBoolean(separarDados(globalResposta, 0).replace("\"", ""));

            } catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
```

Before you all ask, I tried changing the *User-Agent* to Mozilla, AppleWebKit and this stuff. I have also set the permission to access the internet at the manifest.

Comment: try to use StringBuilder istead of StringBuffer. `StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();` StringBuilder not is synchronized and is more faster

Comment: You may not have sufficient balance/data pack. :D

Just kidding, try using some library like Retrofit.

Comment: use a library like volley or retrofit, HttpURLConnection is not recommended or deprecated